# Italicise part of a string in a NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tableData addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"ONE" @" " @"TWO", @"NEXT CELL", nil]];
```

I want the `@"TWO"` to be in italics. Anyone have any idea how?

Comment: This has nothing to do with NSArray.

Comment: And why do you create the array, then create another array to initialize it, vs just initializing the original array??

Answer (score 0):

Styling information for text is part of NSAttributedString, rather than plain NSString. You'll need to convert to that, then add an attribute for the italic range.

Comment: Thanks! any idea on how I could float it to the right of a UITableCell?

Comment: That doesn't sound like it'd be a property of the string. I don't know though, I rarely do UI programming, and when I do it's for Mac rather than iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `NSString` out of your array (most probably using `objectAtIndex`: method).

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Hey", @"Hello"];

NSString *source = [myArray objectAtIndex: 0];

NSAttributedString destination = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: source attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12]}];
```

This will return you a destination object with italicized text of size 12; you can specify font size of your choice.